# Iterate an array with different pipe-arguments

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, pipe

I have an Array like this:

```
ARRAY=(one two three four five)
```

And I want to Ilterate this Array in a for loop. But when I read the Array I want to change the output. Like this:

```
on
tw
thre
fou
fiv
```

So my question is, how do I do that? I got something like that:

```
for (( i=0; i<${ARRAYLENGTH}; i++ ));
do
echo "$({ARRAY[$i]} | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)"
done
```

But It doesn't Work. It Interpretes my pipe argumentes as an echo output.

What can I do?

Comment: How is your "array" defined? What you have shown us doesn't look like bash syntax. Please [edit] your question to provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: @TomFenech I tried to fill it with more information.

Comment: @JMAD2016 you are missing } after `ldapquery` variable. it should read as something similar to `cn:   $(${ldapquery[$i]} | grep xxx)`

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde Thanks, edited it.

Comment: @JMAD2016 also $ is missing it should be `${ldapquery[$i]}` because ldapquery is command to be expanded.

Comment: I mean this is exactly my question. How do I call this array with pipes @AbhijeetKasurde

Comment: We need to know the exact output of the `ldapsearch` command that you are using and the exact format of the corresponding output that you are trying to produce.

Comment: updated it. this is the exactly output and my format in which i need it.@TomFenech

Comment: It's still unclear what the output of the command is. It's rarely safe to assume that you can just write `my_array=( $(some_command) )` and end up with the right thing.

Comment: this works for me `ARRAY=(one two three four five);
for (( i=0; i<${#ARRAY[@]}; i++ ));
do
    echo ${ARRAY[$i]} | rev | cut -c 2- | rev;
done`  I don't understand what do you want as output ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this should work.

```
pipea[0]="awk -F[=,] '{print \$2}' | sed '/^\s*$/d'"
pipea[1]="awk -F[=,] '{print \$2}' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | cut -d ' ' -f2"
pipea[2]="awk -F[=,] '{print \$2}' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | cut -d ' ' -f1"

for (( i=0; i<${int}; i++ ));
do
    echo "
    dn: cn=$(${ldapquery[$i]} | eval ${pipea[0]}),ou=mydomain,dc=saturday,dc=int
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    objectClass: top
    cn:   $(${ldapquery[$i]} | eval ${pipea[0]})
    sn:   $(${ldapquery[$i]} | eval ${pipea[1]})
    givenName=  $(${ldapquery[$i]} | eval ${pipea[2]})
    telephoneNumber $(${ldapquery[$i]} | eval ${pipea[2]})"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't get it work. I updated my question so that it is easier to understand.